# Remove string contents after apostrophe

Tags: python

I am trying to remove string content after apostrophe punctucation mark `'` from a sentence.

For example, given a sentence `This is the world's first engine. You'll learn more about this later.`

The expected output is `This is the world first engine. You learn more about this later.`

I am able to remove the apostrophe ' using `re.sub()`. However, I am unable to remove the contents after the apostrophe

`re.sub(r'[^\w]', ' ', value)`

I have used python `replace()` as well. However, that would not be a generic solution

`value.replace("'s", "")`

Any help is appreciated. Thank You!

Comment: What have you tried yourself? Have you looked into any form of string replacement in Python?

Comment: I think your question has recieved downvotes because you might have tried yourself and searched SO for hours - but there is no evidence of this from your question. Rather than "how do I do X", consider something along the lines of "I'm trying to do X, I've tried the following (and show your code) and explain in what way it's not working or the bit you are stuck on."

Comment: @kabdulla I have edited my question accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove apostrophes and trailing letters within your `str` you could use the below code.

```py
import re

s = "This is the world's first engine. You'll learn more about this later."
s = re.sub(r'\'\w+', '', s)
print(s)
```

**Output**: `This is the world first engine. You learn more about this later.`

The pattern `\'\w+` matches apostrophes followed by one or more word characters, `re.sub()` is used to replace any matches of this pattern with an empty string (`''`).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `re.sub()` as follows

```
import re
def clean(value):
    return re.sub(r'\'\w{,2}', '', value)

print(clean("This is the world's first engine. You'll learn more about this later"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this (i guess there are simpler solutions with regex though):

```
s="This is the world's first engine. You'll learn more about this later."

s=' '.join(list(map(lambda x: x[:x.find("'")] if "'" in x else x, s.split(' '))))

>>> print(s)
'This is the world first engine. You learn more about this later.'
```